# Run multiple javascript code for imacros inside a javascript file (iim, js)

Tags: javascript, macros, imacros

I have Windows 7, Firefox 56, Imacros 8.9.7

I need to run multiple imacros javascript code in sequence one after the other.

With iim imacros extension I can use this command inside the javascript macro starter

Example run_all_macro.js

```
iimPlay("macro1.iim")
iimPlay("macro2.iim")
iimPlay("macro3.iim")
iimPlay("macro4.iim")
```

I need to run macro in javascript format and this code do not works

Example run_all_macro.js

```
iimPlay("macro1.js")
iimPlay("macro2.js")
iimPlay("macro3.js")
iimPlay("macro4.js")
```

Example of macro1.js

```
var imacros = "PROXY ADDRESS=12.3.4.5:67" + "\n";
imacros += "URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElemensByClassName('class_here')[0].click();undefined;}" + "\n";
iimPlayCode(imacros);
```

How can i run multiple javascript code inside a javascript code ?

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: I need to run multiple different macro written in javascript with firefox settings update and i do not find a solution to start all the macros in sequence. the code are written in javascript